# Wrong number of arguments, debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on debugging some code I've been working on to try and get it "clean" before moving on. At a certain point I began getting Failures from my guard terminal so I stopped and cleaned them up.

This has been an on and off project for me so I am not sure exactly what changed but now I have 19 wrong number of argument (1 for 0) errors. These errors didn't exist before so I am not quite sure why they do now.

My question is, how should I go about finding the source of this issue? There are many of the same error on different files that all showed up at the same time. I'm guessing there must be a common thread but I am not seeing it.

My Google foo has not been strong enough to find pertinent information on my problem because "wrong number of arguments" is fairly generic.

Any help, suggestions, or general guidance are welcome. Thanks in advance.

bitbucket repo:
[FermiInventory](https://bitbucket.org/beaunus/fermiinventory/src/345e027867ea4958a78157566f60af218ecf2073?at=log-in-log-out)

An example of my test results:

```
    [1] guard(main)> 
04:02:05 - INFO - Run all
04:02:05 - INFO - Running: all tests
Started

ERROR["test_valid_item_information", NewItemTest, 2.466063744]
 test_valid_item_information#NewItemTest (2.47s)
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
            app/controllers/items_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
            app/controllers/items_controller.rb:30:in `create'
            test/integration/new_item_test.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <class:NewItemTest>'
            test/integration/new_item_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:NewItemTest>'
        app/controllers/items_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
        app/controllers/items_controller.rb:30:in `create'
        test/integration/new_item_test.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <class:NewItemTest>'
        test/integration/new_item_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:NewItemTest>'

  37/37: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:02, Time: 00:00:02

Finished in 2.47525s
37 tests, 41 assertions, 0 failures, 19 errors, 0 skips
```

test/integration/new_item_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class NewItemTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid item information" do
    get newitem_path
    assert_no_difference 'Item.count' do
      post items_path, item: {  name: "" }
    end
    assert_template 'items/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
  end

  test "valid item information" do
    get newitem_path
    name    = "Example Item"
    user_id = 1
    assert_difference 'Item.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect items_path, item: { name:     name,
                                            user_id:  user_id }
    end
    assert_template 'items/show'
    assert_not flash.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: Had a peek at your code, and notice that line 21 of test/integration/new_item_test.rb has user_id = "SomeString". I'm guessing this is going to blow up the moment you try to save an item since the Item model says it is an integer field used to relate associate the item with a user.

Comment: I believe this is fixed in the most recent commit. user_id = 1

Comment: You probably need to show some code.  when I look at the line that roob pointed out I see user_id = "Beau Harrison".  Also you mention this was based on Michael Hartl's Tutorial?  I am familiar with it, but what you have in the repo is different from the tutorial.  It was a while ago, so I went back and took a quick look, and as an example I don't even see a items model mentioned. The point is, either post some code or make sure the repo you are pointing us to is the actual code you are running.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion I am not sure why you are seeing something other than the newest commit. I am not exactly sure what code to post as I am unsure of the problem but I have added the new_item_test.rb post above. Also, I am using the tutorial as a guide as I modify for my application. Once again, I apologize is this caused confusion.

Comment: where is the `app/controllers/items_controller.rb`?

Comment: It's there... Not sure why you can't see it. I have updated the bitbucket link to take you straight to the appropriate branch and source.